# Silverlight receives remote server returned an error Not Found, and the service continues to run and ends perfectly

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis, timeout

I have a silverlight application, when I call a WCF service that takes longer than two minutes, I get the error "remote server returned an error Not Found", execution continues on the server, it ends perfectly. I know that, because of the results in the database tables and because I get an email at the end of the run.

in client:

```
cliente.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
```

in server

```
<binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="02:30:00" openTimeout="02:30:00" receiveTimeout="02:30:00" sendTimeout="02:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
```

If the execution takes less than two minutes, I got a return. Already tested with a loop that expected 2 minutes and get a return, it worked perfectly. By increasing the loop time to three minutes I get the same error: "remote server returned an error Not Found".

Comment: What is the question? The client side Silverlight behavior is expected as it assumes the server does not respond in time. You should change timeout settings or redesign server side to respond faster.

Comment: Could you tell me where to, because "SendTimeout" is in 2 hours 30 minutes and "OperationTimeout" is in an hour, do not understand why always after two minutes got the error.

Comment: If possible, please capture network packets on both client and server side to see how the TCP connection stops. I guess there is a proxy in between whose timeout is 2 minutes. Of course, there can be other factors, but without network packet captures you will never know.